# With the Rubberduck VBE add in is there a way to disable inspections on a module level?

Tags: vba, rubberduck

I have a few modules in my project that either:

use code from the internet that I don't understand but works so I don't want to touch them

or use really old, unmaintainable code that is in the process of being replaced

I am aware of the `@Ignore` annotation but is there a way to ignore **ALL** inspections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out
`@Ignore` requires additional parameters
`@IgnoreModule` ignores everything without needing additional parameters

More info
https://rubberduckvba.com/Annotations/Details/Ignore
https://rubberduckvba.com/Annotations/Details/IgnoreModule